# vim 'a' key meaning in normal mode

Tags: vim

In vim, when you type `a` in normal mode, you go into insert mode after cursor. But `daw` will delete word under cursor and `caw` will change word under cursor. I use these combinations very often, it very helpful. But what does `a` mean in this context and can it be useful in other cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim being a (the?) modal editor, the keys on your keyboard have different meanings depending on which mode you are in.

In normal mode, `a` means "append". It enters insert mode and whatever key you press after that is inserted in your buffer.

In normal mode, `c`, `d` and `y` are called "operators". When you press one of those keys, you quit normal mode and enter another mode called "operator-pending mode" where Vim waits for you to feed it a motion or text-object.

In operator-pending mode, a single `a` means nothing but `aw` is one of those text-objects and could be translated as "around word". There's also `iw` for "inner word" or `at` for "around tag" and many others…

Reference:

```
:help vim-modes
:help navigation

and more specifically

:help operator
:help text-objects
:help word-motions and following
```

Comment: oh thank you sir, especially for help references, I didn't know what keywords use to find it.